# possibility to control embedded video timeline with buttons and links external to the player

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields, timestamp, video-player

I am a designer working on a Wordpress website, currently, I need to make a page where there can be displayed an **external video** (can be from almost any URL) but I want to include some functionality that allows adding links in the text or buttons that actually makes the player go to a specific moment (something similar to Timestamp in youtube videos) in the timeline of the video.

Currently, I am using the *Elementor pro* page builder to construct this site as my programming skills are limited as my role as a designer.

Do you know if Wordpress offers any alternative to do it?

Also, if you need it will require programming skills, what would you think would be the best option to approach this problem?

English is not my native language I hope the explanation of my problem is easy to understand.

Thanks!

update:

so I've found out with a coworker that this could actually help

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe name="myiframe" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?start=47&autoplay=1" target="myiframe" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture">Foo</a>

</body>
</html>
```

but again I need this to work with more sites, not only youtube urls. I need also at least a way to change some parts of the url dynamically in the page/post editor.

update2:

I found out that an easy aproach to this problem is to use ACF plugin to add a field, because with a [shortcut](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/) it might be easy to edit the start time in the url, I never did something like that and the link dissapears when I add the shortcut remplacing that fragment.

like:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jAc3L2NQbA8?start=[acf field="number" post_id="7"]&autoplay=1" target="myiframe" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture">Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so by now I've found a plugin that does exactly what I need, its called [skip to Timestamp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/skip-to-timestamp/) so basically it allows to use a shortcut or even just interpretate timecodes like 1:00 to make the video go straight to that point. It works perfectly with youtube videos but it also works with  and  tag. By now is the best option I have.

Comment: Doesn't work on rumble videos. I desperately need to make this work for a rumble video. Any suggestion would be appreciated.